# Java different Calculator basic functions problem?

Tags: java

The code below is a chunk from actual code of Calculator.What it does is that user presses a number on the calculator then as he presses "+" the number on the text field gets stored and then he presses the next number and it gets stored when he presses "=".Then in "=" if condition the addition function is performed.Now i want both addition and subtraction running at one time that is after doing addition user wants to do subtraction then HOW will i do it????

```
if(a.getActionCommand().equals("+"))
{
   q=tf.getText();
   x=Integer.parseInt(q);
}

if(a.getActionCommand().equals("-"))
{
   b=tf.getText();
   t=Integer.parseInt(b);
}
if(a.getActionCommand().equals("="))
{
   p=tf.getText();
   y=Integer.parseInt(p);
   z=x+y;
   //z=t-y;
   w=Integer.toString(z);
   tf.setText(w);
}
```

Comment: Basically i had some time so thought of making a calculator in java so that i can practice my gui course before exams.

Answer (score 1):

Calculators generally perform an `=` operation whenever they process an action like `+` or `-`.  Try it, open the calc app on your computer now and try `3 + 5 - 1`.  When you press the `-`, the display will show `8`.  You can do the same with yours and handle as many `+` and `-` operations in a row as you would like.  There would be some refactoring to do to the code you've posted, and one thing you could do there would be to methodize the process that you use for the `=` operation. You could then call that `performEquals` at the beginning of each `+` or `-` block.

Answer (score 1):

A stack based algorithm as jcomeau_ictx suggests is a very viable solution to your problem.

Create two stacks: one that holds operators (+, -, *, /) and one that holds operands (the set of numbers 0-9).

Support the user presses: 3 + 4 - 5

```
Steps:

1.) Push '3' into the operand stack
2.) Push '+' into the operator stack
3.) Push '4' into the operand stack.

Since there are at least 2 operands, calculate 3 + 4 (which is 7).

4.) Pop 3 and 4.  Add these two and pop them to the operand stack
5.) Pop + from the operator stack and push -.
6.) Push 5 onto the stack.  Subtract these two and place result in operand stack.
```

General Algorithm:

```
Push operand (or operator) into the stack
if (operands > 2 && operator > 0)
     pop both operands and one operator;
     calculate result;
     place result in operand stack;
     reset operator stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: accept a negative number as input, then add? Or am I missing the point?

If not, then using RPN would work, no need for "=" at all. Enter two numbers, then the "+" or "-" will take the two operands off the stack, apply the operator, and push the result back onto the stack, displaying it.

Third way: instead of your code for "-", use:

```
if(a.getActionCommand().equals("-"))
{
   b=tf.getText();
   x=-(Integer.parseInt(b));
}
```

Not sure if I've taken everything into account on that last suggestion, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have 4 operations ( +, - , ×, ÷ ), and that you're implementing a basic desktop calculator that **doesn't implement order of operations**. In this case, [jcomeau_ictx's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295293/java-different-calculator-basic-functions-problem/4295360#4295360) `x=-(Integer.parseInt(b))` won't work because it can only deal with subtraction, not multiplication and division, and these stack-based solutions are overkill.

What you is 3 variables: `firstNumber`, `operation` and `secondNumber`. `operation` starts out empty (or using some value that indicates "empty"). When the user hits =, what you need to do is take the number from the display and put it into `secondNumber`. Then look at all 3 variables and perform the indicated in the `operation` variable.

When the user hits +, - , ×, or  ÷, first you perform the = operation (put the user's input into `secondNumber` and perform the operation indicated by the `operation` variable). Put the result into `firstNumber` (and display it on the screen if you wish). Then store the operation that the user hit (+, - , ×, or  ÷) in the `operation` variable, so that you can perform that operation the *next time* the user hits +, - , ×, ÷, or =.