# Simple GUI Java calculator

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I am building a simple GUI Java calculator. I have an issue finding a package or figuring out a method to do the actual calculation. So far I've figured that when I do a math operation, the number in the text box gets saved in a temporary location.

Then when I click on the `"="` button, it will do the calculation, but I don't know how to tell it to take the temporary plus the math operation and the second number and do the calculation based on the selected math operation clicked, `+, -, *, /`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaCalculator extends JFrame {
    private JButton jbtNum1;
        private JButton jbtNum2;
        private JButton jbtNum3;
        private JButton jbtNum4;
        private JButton jbtNum5;
        private JButton jbtNum6;
        private JButton jbtNum7;
        private JButton jbtNum8;
        private JButton jbtNum9;
        private JButton jbtNum0;
    private JButton jbtEqual;
        private JButton jbtAdd;
        private JButton jbtSubtract;
        private JButton jbtMultiply;
        private JButton jbtDivide;
        private JButton jbtSolve;
        private JButton jbtClear;
        private double TEMP;
        private double SolveTEMP;
    private JTextField jtfResult;
    String display = "";

    public JavaCalculator() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        p1.add(jbtNum1 = new JButton("1"));
        p1.add(jbtNum2 = new JButton("2"));
        p1.add(jbtNum3 = new JButton("3"));
        p1.add(jbtNum4 = new JButton("4"));
        p1.add(jbtNum5 = new JButton("5"));
        p1.add(jbtNum6 = new JButton("6"));
        p1.add(jbtNum7 = new JButton("7"));
        p1.add(jbtNum8 = new JButton("8"));
        p1.add(jbtNum9 = new JButton("9"));
        p1.add(jbtNum0 = new JButton("0"));
        p1.add(jbtClear = new JButton("C"));


        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(jtfResult = new JTextField(20));
        jtfResult.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfResult.setEditable(false);

                JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
                p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                p3.add(jbtAdd = new JButton("+"));
                p3.add(jbtSubtract = new JButton("-"));
                p3.add(jbtMultiply = new JButton("*"));
                p3.add(jbtDivide = new JButton("/"));
                p3.add(jbtSolve = new JButton("="));

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        p.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);


        add(p);

        jbtNum1.addActionListener(new ListenToOne());
        jbtNum2.addActionListener(new ListenToTwo());
        jbtNum3.addActionListener(new ListenToThree());
                jbtNum4.addActionListener(new ListenToFour());
        jbtNum5.addActionListener(new ListenToFive());
        jbtNum6.addActionListener(new ListenToSix());
        jbtNum7.addActionListener(new ListenToSeven());
        jbtNum8.addActionListener(new ListenToEight());
        jbtNum9.addActionListener(new ListenToNine());
        jbtNum0.addActionListener(new ListenToZero());

        jbtAdd.addActionListener(new ListenToAdd());
        jbtSubtract.addActionListener(new ListenToSubtract());
        jbtMultiply.addActionListener(new ListenToMultiply());
        jbtDivide.addActionListener(new ListenToDivide());
        jbtSolve.addActionListener(new ListenToSolve());



    } //JavaCaluclator()

    class ListenToOne implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
        }
    }
    class ListenToTwo implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "2");
        }
    }
    class ListenToThree implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "3");
        }
    }
    class ListenToFour implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "4");
        }
    }
    class ListenToFive implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "5");
        }
    }
    class ListenToSix implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "6");
        }
    }
    class ListenToSeven implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "7");
        }
    }
    class ListenToEight implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "8");
        }
    }
    class ListenToNine implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "9");
        }
    }
    class ListenToZero implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
    }

        class ListenToAdd implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
                        jtfResult.setText("");

        }
    }
    class ListenToSubtract implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
    }
    class ListenToMultiply implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
    }
    class ListenToDivide implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
    }
    class ListenToSolve implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        SolveTEMP = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(TEMP + Double.parseDouble(jtfResult);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JavaCalculator calc = new JavaCalculator();
        calc.pack();
        calc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        calc.setVisible(true);
    }

} //JavaCalculator
```

Comment: How do i program the `=` button so it can do the calcualtion?

Comment: You should use an array of buttons; that will cut your code size by something like 70%.

Comment: right now im trying to make it work, not trying to be efficient...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java different Calculator basic functions problem???? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295293/java-different-calculator-basic-functions-problem)

Comment: Now I'm getting **really** suspicious that someone assigned a GUI calculator as a class assignment and multiple students are asking how to do it here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 11):

This is the working code...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaCalculator extends JFrame {

    private JButton jbtNum1;
    private JButton jbtNum2;
    private JButton jbtNum3;
    private JButton jbtNum4;
    private JButton jbtNum5;
    private JButton jbtNum6;
    private JButton jbtNum7;
    private JButton jbtNum8;
    private JButton jbtNum9;
    private JButton jbtNum0;
    private JButton jbtEqual;
    private JButton jbtAdd;
    private JButton jbtSubtract;
    private JButton jbtMultiply;
    private JButton jbtDivide;
    private JButton jbtSolve;
    private JButton jbtClear;
    private double TEMP;
    private double SolveTEMP;
    private JTextField jtfResult;

    Boolean addBool = false;
    Boolean subBool = false;
    Boolean divBool = false;
    Boolean mulBool = false;

    String display = "";

    public JavaCalculator() {

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        p1.add(jbtNum1 = new JButton("1"));
        p1.add(jbtNum2 = new JButton("2"));
        p1.add(jbtNum3 = new JButton("3"));
        p1.add(jbtNum4 = new JButton("4"));
        p1.add(jbtNum5 = new JButton("5"));
        p1.add(jbtNum6 = new JButton("6"));
        p1.add(jbtNum7 = new JButton("7"));
        p1.add(jbtNum8 = new JButton("8"));
        p1.add(jbtNum9 = new JButton("9"));
        p1.add(jbtNum0 = new JButton("0"));
        p1.add(jbtClear = new JButton("C"));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(jtfResult = new JTextField(20));
        jtfResult.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfResult.setEditable(false);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        p3.add(jbtAdd = new JButton("+"));
        p3.add(jbtSubtract = new JButton("-"));
        p3.add(jbtMultiply = new JButton("*"));
        p3.add(jbtDivide = new JButton("/"));
        p3.add(jbtSolve = new JButton("="));

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        p.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        add(p);

        jbtNum1.addActionListener(new ListenToOne());
        jbtNum2.addActionListener(new ListenToTwo());
        jbtNum3.addActionListener(new ListenToThree());
        jbtNum4.addActionListener(new ListenToFour());
        jbtNum5.addActionListener(new ListenToFive());
        jbtNum6.addActionListener(new ListenToSix());
        jbtNum7.addActionListener(new ListenToSeven());
        jbtNum8.addActionListener(new ListenToEight());
        jbtNum9.addActionListener(new ListenToNine());
        jbtNum0.addActionListener(new ListenToZero());

        jbtAdd.addActionListener(new ListenToAdd());
        jbtSubtract.addActionListener(new ListenToSubtract());
        jbtMultiply.addActionListener(new ListenToMultiply());
        jbtDivide.addActionListener(new ListenToDivide());
        jbtSolve.addActionListener(new ListenToSolve());
        jbtClear.addActionListener(new ListenToClear());
    } //JavaCaluclator()

    class ListenToClear implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText("");
            addBool = false;
            subBool = false;
            mulBool = false;
            divBool = false;

            TEMP = 0;
            SolveTEMP = 0;
        }
    }

    class ListenToOne implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
        }
    }

    class ListenToTwo implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "2");
        }
    }

    class ListenToThree implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "3");
        }
    }

    class ListenToFour implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "4");
        }
    }

    class ListenToFive implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "5");
        }
    }

    class ListenToSix implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "6");
        }
    }

    class ListenToSeven implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "7");
        }
    }

    class ListenToEight implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "8");
        }
    }

    class ListenToNine implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "9");
        }
    }

    class ListenToZero implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display = jtfResult.getText();
            jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
    }

    class ListenToAdd implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            jtfResult.setText("");
            addBool = true;
        }
    }

    class ListenToSubtract implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            jtfResult.setText("");
            subBool = true;
        }
    }

    class ListenToMultiply implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            jtfResult.setText("");
            mulBool = true;
        }
    }

    class ListenToDivide implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            jtfResult.setText("");
            divBool = true;
        }
    }

    class ListenToSolve implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SolveTEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            if (addBool == true)
                SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP + TEMP;
            else if ( subBool == true)
                SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP - TEMP;
            else if ( mulBool == true)
                SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP * TEMP;
            else if ( divBool == true)
                            SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP / TEMP;
            jtfResult.setText(  Double.toString(SolveTEMP));

            addBool = false;
            subBool = false;
            mulBool = false;
            divBool = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JavaCalculator calc = new JavaCalculator();
        calc.pack();
        calc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        calc.setVisible(true);
    }

} //JavaCalculator
```

Comment: Maybe, but there is way too much redundancy. E.g. `display = jtfResult.getText(); jtfResult.setText(display + "X");` appears 10 times, with only "X" being different.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have to keep track of what button had been pressed. When things happen, you need to store something in a variable so you can recall the information or it's gone forever.

When someone pressed one of the operator buttons, don't just let them type in another value. Save the operator symbol, then let them type in another value. You could literally just have a `String operator` that gets the text of the operator button pressed. Then, when the equals button is pressed, you have to check to see which operator you stored. You could do this with an if/else if/else chain.

So, in your symbol's button press event, store the symbol text in a variable, then, in the = button press event, check to see which symbol is in the variable and act accordingly.

Alternatively, if you feel comfortable enough with enums (looks like you're just starting, so if you're not to that point yet, ignore this), you could have an enumeration of symbols that lets you check symbols easily with a switch.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something that calculates the result of the [infix notated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) calculation, have a look at the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

There's an example in C++ on Wikipedia's page, but it shouldn't be too hard to implement it in Java.
And since it's the primary function of your calculator, I would advise you to not grab some *codez* from the Web in this Case (except all you want to do is building calculator GUIs).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that string1 is your whole operation

use mdas

```
double result;
string recurAndCheck(string operation){
  if(operation.indexOf("/")){
     String leftSide = recurAndCheck(operation.split("/")[0]);
     string rightSide = recurAndCheck(operation.split("/")[1]);
     result = Double.parseDouble(leftSide)/Double.parseDouble(rightSide);

  } else if (..continue w/ *...) {
    //same as above but change / with *
  } else if (..continue w/ -) { 
    //change as above but change with -
  } else if (..continuew with +) {
    //change with add
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```